# Gulp-uncss ignore option

Tags: javascript, gulp, uncss

The ignore option doesn't seem to be working for me.

I'm doing the following:

```
    .pipe(plugins.uncss({
        html: glob.sync('./**/*.{csh,h}tml'),
        ignore: ['.active']
    })
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing _precisely_?

Comment: the classes in the ignore array are not ignored by uncss. They are also removed.

Comment: Have you tried using the regex form like `/active/`

Comment: Will post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the regex form for your `ignore` option:

```
.pipe(plugins.uncss({
  html: glob.sync('./**/*.{csh,h}tml'),
  ignore: ['/active/']
})
```